# Формула до фундаментальной матрицы решений системы линейных дифференциальных уравнений с постоянной матрицей

Tags: математика, матрицы

Как выглядит эта формула? И после этого, как ее вывести? Не очень понимаю, что под ней подразумевается.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не относится к программированию.